# How can I make Layout for Small than 3" screen and Layout for 4.8" screen (Android)

Tags: android, layout, screen

I have an Android app, my design for 3.2" between 4". What can I make for different screen? like another layouts folder or in programmatically code. My apps don't showing correctly to 3" , and > 4.8".

I think

if device screen< 3"

layout zoom -

if device screen >=4.7

layout zoom +

Answer (score 0):

Android has a lot of really nice tools to help developers deal with multiple screen sizes and densities.  You can read more about how it all works at this [Android Developers Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: so , is think possible ? i think

Answer (score 0):

You have to create specific images for each different screens that you want to support and distribute it in the correct resources folder, and use the dimen file to your margins, txt sizes and so on.

```
320dp: a typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, 480x800 hdpi, etc).
480dp: a tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi).
600dp: a 7” tablet (600x1024 mdpi).
720dp: a 10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

for different screens the android manages it self if you use the correct reference in your layout folder like:

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

For more information is essential read the documentation [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: you can use even the argument -land if you have a diferent layout for landscape orientation, everything you need to do is read the documentation e follow it.